# Meaning of $\operatorname{UOWH}(k; u_1, u_2)$

Tags: hash, universal-hash

I do not understand the format used in [*Shoup's "Using Hash Functions as a Hedge against Chosen Ciphertext Attack (page 8 of the PDF)*](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070279-new.pdf) for universal one way hash functions (UOWH). What are $k$, $u_1$ and $u_2$ in $\operatorname{UOWH}(k; u_1, u_2)$?

Comment: I'd suppose that $k$ is some "keying input" to the universal hash function and I _guess_ that $u_1,u_2=u_1\parallel u_2$ that $,$ denotes concatenation or maybe pairing in this context.

Answer (score 2):

If you look up the reference [BR97] in the paper, it clearly states that $k$ is the key which is used to select a hash function from a family of hash functions and the rest of the part of the input i.e. $u_1, u_2, u_3 ...$ is the input to the selected hash such that $u_i$ is the input to $UOWH(k;u_1,u_2,...,u_i-1)$ 
[image: Here is the image from [BR97 paper]]

Comment: This is considering that $u_i$ takes up a block size of the hash.